# AWS amplify has Mutations working with Cognito User but not queries

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have setup a GraphQL schema using AWS Amplify.
Here is the schema:

```
type User @model @auth(rules: [
  { allow: owner}
]) {
  firstName: String!
  lastName: String!
  userId: String! @primaryKey
  phoneNumber: String
  email: String!
}

type Listing @model @searchable
  @auth(rules: [
    { allow: public, operations: [read] },
    { allow: owner, operations: [create, update, delete], ownerField: "userId" }
  ]) {
  id: ID!
  type: String!
  rentEstimate: Int!
  latt : Float!,
  long : Float!,
 category: String!
  description: String!
  images: [String]!
  userId: String!
}
```

The strange issue is that I have enabled Cognito User Pools as can be seen here

```
    "aws_appsync_region": "us-east-1",
    "aws_appsync_authenticationType": "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
```

For some reason, I am able to add Listings, update and delete them using the logged in user in App Sync.
Yet, I am unable to run Queries. I can only run queries when I use the API key option is AppSync.
Here is a sample Query that returns the following error for a Logged in user.

Query:

```
query MyQuery {
  listListings(filter: {userId: {eq: "loggedin-username"}}) {
    nextToken
    items {
      category
      description
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "data": {
    "listListings": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "listListings"
      ],
      "data": null,
      "errorType": "Unauthorized",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "Not Authorized to access listListings on type Query"
    }
  ]
}
```

The same works when I use the API_key in AppSync.

I have updated the api to reflect "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening by design
In the document it is stated:

> `To grant everyone access, use the public authorization strategy. Behind the scenes, the API will be protected with an API Key.`

So in your schema, you need to give the owner read access to allow them to view the Listings, otherwise they can only be read via the `API KEY`.

*Change*

```json
{ allow: owner, operations: [create, update, delete], ownerField: "userId" }
```

*To*

```json
//give the owner read access
{ allow: owner, operations: [create, update, delete, read], ownerField: "userId" }
```

[Amplify GraphQL uthorization-strategies](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/authorization-rules/#authorization-strategies)

Comment: How does the call work on the front-end app?
 const result = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(searchListings, {
            filter: {
              type: {
                matchPhrase: "Condo"
              }
            }
          }))
This returns a null for a logged in user.
So, if search needs to be publicly available. How do I make the call on the front end?

Comment: That is because `graphqlOperation ` still needs the API Key as I explained above.
You will need to use`API.graphql()` and pass the query directly.

More Examples and explanations on:
[Amplify GraphQL Client](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/authz/q/platform/js/#using-amplify-graphql-client)